# Excel: how to start macro recording from OLE

Tags: excel, ole

I control Excel instance via OLE and I want to start macro recording. Can I do that via code? The only thing I've found is [Application.RecordMacro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb223571.aspx) and it doesn't do what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't think you can. You could trigger it by using SendKeys.